# QuartzJobBean not executing spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, quartz-scheduler

I have a spring boot project which uses **`spring-boot-starter-quartz, version '2.2.2.RELEASE'`** and **`springBootVersion '1.5.10.RELEASE'`** to schedule jobs.

I am facing an issue randomly where the some of the triggers aren't executed.

The following is the quartz.properties file in my project

```
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount=10
org.quartz.jobStore.class =org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreCMT
org.quartz.job-store-type =jdbc
org.quartz.jobStore.useProperties=false

org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass =org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate
org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix =QRTZ_
org.quartz.dataSource.fieldstar.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
org.quartz.dataSource.fieldstar.maxConnections = 15
org.quartz.scheduler.jobFactory.class = org.quartz.simpl.SimpleJobFactory
```

When I trigger a job, I can see the rows of my triggers in the database table **`QRTZ_TRIGGERS`**.
When the **`START_TIME`** reaches, the triggers are deleted from this table and the implementation provided for this job using **`QuartzJobBean`** is executed for some triggers but not for the rest.

The following is the code to schedule a job.

```
JobBuilder.newJob(CommonReminderListener.class)
                .withIdentity("jobKey")
                .withDescription("Test" + jobKey.getGroup())
                .usingJobData(jobDataMap)
                .storeDurably()
                .build();
```

The following is my implementation for the **`QuartzJobBean`**

```
@Component
public class CommonReminderListener extends QuartzJobBean {

    @Override
    public void executeInternal(JobExecutionContext jobExecutionContext) throws JobExecutionException {
        logger.info("Executing Job with key", jobExecutionContext.getJobDetail().getKey());
    }


}
```

I am not sure what seems to be the problem. Any help is appreciated.